# python-lambda-local self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)

Tags: python-3.7

[root - INFO - 2019-02-11 17:40:38,224] Event: {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
[root - INFO - 2019-02-11 17:40:38,224] START RequestId: f294f11b-4c1e-46f7-b434-e78eb7d9e8ba Version:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\Sekhar.Changalaraya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Sekhar.Changalaraya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request-f294f11b-4c1e-46f7-b434-e78eb7d9e8ba'

def handler(event, context):
    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': 'd'}

Answer (score 0):

Use python-lambda-local==0.1.7 or python-lambda-local==0.1.6

Answer (score 0):

It should already be fixed with v0.1.12 of python-lambda-local.